# Why are ContentLength and AllowWriteStreamBuffering inaccessible in Metro C# apps?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I want to know why `ContentLength` and `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` are not accessible in the `HttpWebRequest` class for Windows Store apps. The answer that shows up here and there on the internet says that the .NET documentation is not up-to-date for Windows Store apps, but this is not the case. MS is either trying to hide these for a reason, to remove them in the future, or it is just a bug that they are not accessible.

I can set these values in the Visual Studio debugger.

These two members are in the class and work as expected. if I specify a content length and then disable write buffering, I can monitor the progress of my large file upload.

So does anyone know the real reason that these are not accessible in my C# code?